# Styling HTML e-mail

Tags: html, css, email, coldfusion

When creating an HTML e-mail how do you specify the appearance, for example the font? Is there a better way than using inline CSS? I'm using `cfmail` to send e-mails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can style it in the `<style>` blocks in the head section, but the best/consistent way to style anything in HTML emails is by doing it inline unfortunately. If you're feeling lazy you can use http://premailer.dialect.ca/ to move everything inline for you.

Answer (score 5):

The most important aspect of html mails is making sure the recipient can read the mail. For this reason it is important to stick to basic HTML and than means inline CSS only i'm afraid.

I use this tool - http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/ 
Source files - https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler